# How to create the liquibase dbchangelog programatically using java code?

Tags: spring, jpa, liquibase, changelog

I recently used the `liquibase` change set to `generateChangelog` , `diff` and `updateSQL` to create the change log, to find the difference and to generate the ddl scripts respectively.

And my change log looked something like this and it was an xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<databaseChangeLog
 xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
 http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">

<changeSet author="John (generated)" id="1439225004329-1">
 <createTable tableName="Author ">
    <column autoIncrement="true" name="id" type="BIGINT">
        <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
    </column> 
    <column name="name" type="VARCHAR(255)"/>
  </createTable>
</changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

I created this xml manually. And I was trying to create the same change log though java code.
I am having an hard time figuring out how to do this in java. Can someone put some light on this?

I have added `liquibase 3.5.5` as `maven dependency` to my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what about this?

```
final Path changeLogPath = Paths.get("/tmp/mychangelog.xml");

final DatabaseChangeLog changeLog = new DatabaseChangeLog(changeLogPath.toString());
changeLog.setPhysicalFilePath("mychangelog.xml");

final CreateTableChange createTableChange = new CreateTableChange();
createTableChange.setTableName("firsttable");
createTableChange.addColumn(new ColumnConfig().setName("col1").setType("VARCHAR(20)"));

final ChangeSet changeSet = new ChangeSet("id1", "author", Boolean.FALSE, Boolean.FALSE, null, null, null, changeLog);
changeSet.addChange(createTableChange);

try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(changeLogPath.toString())){
    serializer.write(changeLog.getChangeSets(), os);
}
```

Comment: it worked thanks... got an idea ! .... how can I use this change log to generate script using java code ? check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55499807/how-to-use-liquibase-programatically-in-java